# Error in the loop

Tags: vba, excel

i have an error in the loop FOR. I don't understand why.My purpose is to activate the option "automatic calculation" then delete all old rows and finally add new ones.

```
Sub refresh()
    '
    ' refresh Macro
    '
    ' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
    '
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer

        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Range("A6:AP1000").Select
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Selection.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Range("A6:AP1000").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

      Sheets("PTR").Range(“A” & Rows.Count).Select

     For i = 2 To Sheets("PTR").Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     If Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
     Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Select
     Selection.Copy
      Sheets("Analyse de risque").Range("B" & Rows.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If
     Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: and this error is...? oh, and don't use microsoft word to edit your code. `“A”` are not valid quotes...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet

Set WS1 = Worksheets("PTR")
LastRow1 = WS1.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row  ' COLUMN 1  ?????????
Set WS2 = Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
LastRow2 = WS2.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row  ' COLUMN 1 ?????

For i = 2 To LastRow1
   If Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
      Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Copy
      WS2.Cells(LastRow2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      LastRow2 = LastRow2 + 1
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.